CSS grid background only in cell with other cells overlaying
I am am trying to lay out the following structure with CSS grid but am confused about the the best way to go about it:

Am just wondering if someone has a suggestion or some sample code with the best way to this out on CSS grid:

background image for main area
menu on left side, header & thumbnails on the right side.

Thanks for any help with this.

Hello, @new_coder
please make sure to follow the posting rules and use [mre] to show us how far you go and we could give you a hand with your help request

What do you want it to look like on different viewport sizes and aspect ratios?

You can create a grid layout for this purpose.
You actually have 3 columns, 5 rows and 3 elements menu, header, thumbnails. So just place the elements in the grid layout.
A sample code below.


* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 30px;
}

.menu {
  background-color: pink;
}

.header {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2;

}

.thumbnail {
  background-color: lime;
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 4;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">Menu</div>
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="thumbnail">Thumbnail</div>
</div>



